# What is the path name for the following location?

Tags: macos

I think the path name to the following location is `G:/Team drives/Google Drive/Shared Drive/BrownCarbon_2019/`, but I do not know whether that is correct.

[image]

Comment: Highly unlikely that you're correct, since Mac OSes don't use drive letters like `G:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Ken and Liel for your answers. The correct path is:

```
/Users/sujaibanerji/Google Drive File Stream/Shared drives/BrownCarbon_2019/
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ken wrote, it is highly unlikely. My bet would be something under `/Users/sujaibanerji`, but there is a better way to know the full path for sure: You can right click on the name of the directory [image: Path shown at the bottom of Finder]

and select `Copy "may" as Pathname`. The correct path would be then copied into the clipboard.